# Angular 2 routes in imported module override current

Tags: angular2-routing

Here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/WIFNVIEVqls4gXk21Muj

There're 2 modules both have routes defined. Module 2 imports module 1 in order to use a component from it. You can never navigate to Module 2. Module 1 loads instead.

Module 1 routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Module1Component }
];
```

Module 2 routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Module2Component }
];
```

App routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'module1', loadChildren: 'app/module1/module1.module#Module1Module' },
  { path: 'module2', loadChildren: 'app/module2/module2.module#Module2Module' }
];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Two issues to get this working. First, there is a bug with the router that takes in account the order of your imported modules. For more details on the error, see this bug report: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12648

So to get around the bug, you need to change the order of your imports in module2.module.ts so that your module2 routing file is imported before you import module1.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        routing, // this order is important
        Module1Module
    ],
    declarations: [
        Module2Component
    ]
})
```

Second, instead of exporting your routing module as a const using ModuleWithProviders export it as a class. aka change the module2 routing file (module2.routing.ts) to export a class like so (you'll need to import NgModule):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class routing {
}
```

This should fix it for you. Here's a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5impstull9EBCUxlw26k

Comment: Good job providing code and explaining it. Really improves the quality of your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I see the order issue but what difference does it make to export as a class?

Comment: I didn't really dig into why you need to export the routing module as a class. I just noticed in the latest angular docs that their examples all export it as a class [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). And when I made that change it started working. Possibly angular deprecated that other method? Not sure.

Comment: Its also funny how defining the routes directly with the feature modules, didn't work either, I had to export the routes from another NgModule to make it count

Comment: I had a similar problem while importing a child module into another that caused similar named child routes to overlap. Managed to solve it following @eddierunner answer. I don't know whether this is a bug or is suppossed to work this way but i find this rather confusing. Having two child routes under different root routes should not cause this kind of conflict. That's the whole point of routing isn't it?