# Angular: importing child module into another child module overwrites latter's routes

Tags: angular, import, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-module

I have this hierarchy in my application:

```
app/
    app.module.ts
    app.routing.ts
    ...
    endpoints/
              endpoints.module.ts
              endpoints.service.ts
              endpoints.routing.ts
              ...
    indexes/
              indexes.module.ts
              indexes.routing.ts
              ...
```

The contains of my routing files:

**app.routing.ts**

```
...
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [{
            path: 'endpoints',
            loadChildren: './endpoints/endpoints.module#EndpointModule'
    },{
            path: 'indexes',
            loadChildren: './indexes/indexes.module#IndexModule'
    }
}];
```

**endpoints.routing.ts**

```
...
export const EndpointRoutes: Routes = [
    {    
        path: '',
        component: EndpointComponent
    }
];
```

**indexes.routing.ts**

```
...
export const IndexesRoutes: Routes = [
    {    
        path: '',
        component: IndexesComponent
    }
];
```

This is straightforward: when i call /endpoints/ the EndpointComponent gets called. Same for /indexes/ and IndexesComponent.

Now, I want to use the endpoints service in my indexes module. I add it to my **indexes.module.ts** which looks like this:

```
...
import { EndpointsModule } from '../endpoints/endpoints.module';
import { EndpointsService } from '../endpoints/endpoints.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(IndexRoutes),
        EndpointsModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        IndexComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        EndpointService
    ]
})

export class IndexModule {}
```

This compiles fine. But now, when I load /indexes/, the view for /endpoints/ shows up. I guess it is importing the routing from the endpoints module too but I don't fully understand how imports work yet. The main module and endpoints module files looks like this (showing the routing related bits since i think are the relevant ones to my problem):

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routing';
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MainComponent, 
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
        ...
    ],
    ...
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**endpoints.module.ts**

```
...
import { EndpointRoutes } from './endpoints.routing';
...

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [

        RouterModule.forChild(EndpointRoutes),
        ...
    ],
})
export class EndpointModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so much in module imports as it is in paths overwriting. In your first example, you have a clear distinction: two different modules on different subpaths.

In your second example, you say `path: 'endpoints'`, then your lazy router adds a route for `''` (which, all things put together, resolves to `/endpoints`, and then *that* module imports another one, which has the same, `''` path, so still the same endpoint.

You really should add both routes lazily loaded from main app component. They're lazy so you're not saving anything extra unless you actually call this route.

Comment: By "adding the routes lazily loaded from the main app component", you mean adding them directly in the main routing file as children (instead of using loadChildren)?

Comment: Nono, lazy means loadChildren.

Comment: I finally had this working. As @Zlatko said it is a thing of paths overwritting, but it took me a while figuring out the solution. If someone has this issue, this answers addresses the situation -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42707482/995014. Basically: 1) convert your routes into a module and export them as a class 2) always import your routes before the child module. There is a plunker in that answer that shows the code.